# Why doesn't the animation disappear as the screen loads on it for 0.5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, loader

I want the animation to disappear for 0.5 seconds as soon as it loads.

codepen.io/codemakker/pen/abJpwjr

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please don't forget to indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want the group to fade away or not, but if you just want the group to disappear after the animation is done and reappear after 0.5 seconds, you can just add the following code:

```
const svg = document.querySelector('svg') // selecting entire svg group

setTimeout(() => {
  svg.style.opacity = 0

  setTimeout(() => {
    svg.style.opacity = 1
  }, 500)
}, 3000)
```

In this example, I'm using a setTimeout within a setTimeout.  The animation takes 3 seconds, so I'm making sure to not to set the svg's opacity to 0 until the animation is over.  Once the svg's opacity is 0, we can use the other setTimeout to set its opacity back to 1 after 0.5 seconds.

---

BONUS:

A more elegant way to solve this problem would be to use Promises instead of using the nested callbacks above.  To do that, you can make a custom delay function that returns a promise after a specified amount of time.  Then you can use that delay function in an asynchronous function, which will wait for each delay function to finish executing before moving to other tasks.

Here's the code:

```
const svg = document.querySelector('svg')

// delay function returns Promise after "ms" amount of time
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
)

// this is the asynchronous function that would execute the animation
const blinkSvg = async () => {
  await delay(3000) // wait for 3s/3000ms before moving to next line
  svg.style.opacity = 0

  await delay(500)
  svg.style.opacity = 1
}

blinkSvg()
```